# How to alert once in a JavaScript forEach function?

Tags: javascript

I have this function `ShowInScreen(ListOfObject)` which receives a list of objects, and then i want to alert in the screen the names of the products that exist in the list, but just once. I'm using `bootbox.alert` that is a bootstrap modal but is the same as alert. Right now is displaying one alert for each object, but i want to display the complete list of objects **in one alert** to show the names of the products, How can i do that?

```
function ShowInScreen(ListOfObject) {
   var ListOfProduct = ListOfObject;

   ListOfProduct.forEach(function (entry) 
   {
      bootbox.alert(entry.product.name);
   });

}
```

Comment: Just collect them into a string variable and show it outside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just build a string in the for loop then alert it

```
var myString;
forEach(function (entry {
     myString += entry.product.name;
}
alert(myString);
```

Answer (score 4):

Add it to an array and use [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
function ShowInScreen(ListOfObject) {
    var productNames = [];

    ListOfObject.forEach(function (entry) 
    {
        productNames.push(entry.product.name);
    });

    bootbox.alert(productNames.join(', ')); //product1, product2, product3
}
```